# Definite integral involving inverse regularized incomplete beta functions

Tags: integration, special-functions, hypergeometric-functions

In my research I encountered the following integral
$$J = \int_0^1 I_t^{-1}(a_1,b_1) \: I_t^{-1}(a_2,b_2) \: \mathrm{d}t$$ 
which I would like to evaluate as a closed form expression, that is, as a function of the parameters $a_{1}, b_{1}, a_{2}, b_{2} >0$. In words, this is the integral of the product of two inverse regularized incomplete beta functions.

This was [posted in Math StackExchange about two months back](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1970571/integral-of-product-of-two-inverse-regularized-incomplete-beta-functions) but received no answer. That link shows my naive attempt via integration by parts. If a closed form (or lack of it) is well known, I would appreciate a reference. Any ideas or approximation for the integral are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

for $a_1=a_2$ and $b_1=b_2$ there is a closed form expression in terms of the incomplete Beta function:

abbreviate $Q_t=I^{-1}_t(a,b)$ and then *Mathematica* tells me that

$$\int_0^1 Q_t^2 \,dt=\frac{1}{bB(a,b)}$$
$$\times\left[(1-Q_0){}^b Q_0{}^{a+1}-(1-Q_1){}^b Q_1{}^{a+1}+(a+1) B_{Q_1}(a+1,b+1)-(a+1)B_{Q_0}(a+1,b+1)\right]$$

I would be surprised if this can be generalized to $a_1\neq a_2$, $b_1\neq b_2$.

Comment: In fact, since $Q_{0} = 0$, $Q_{1} = 1$, hence in this special case the integral equals to a rational function of parameters: $\int_{0}^{1} Q_{t}^{2} \: dt = \frac{a(a+1)}{(a+b)(a+b+1)}$.